# Differences between POSIX threads on OSX and LINUX?

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, concurrency, pthreads

Can anyone shed light on the reason that when the below code is compiled and run on OSX the 'bartender' thread skips through the `sem_wait()` in what seems like a random manner and yet when compiled and run on a Linux machine the `sem_wait()` holds the thread until the relative call to `sem_post()` is made, as would be expected?

I am currently learning not only POSIX threads but concurrency as a whole so absoutely any comments, tips and insights are warmly welcomed...

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

//using namespace std;

#define NSTUDENTS 30
#define MAX_SERVINGS 100

void* student(void* ptr);
void get_serving(int id);
void drink_and_think();

void* bartender(void* ptr);
void refill_barrel();


// This shared variable gives the number of servings currently in the barrel
int servings = 10;

// Define here your semaphores and any other shared data
sem_t *mutex_stu;
sem_t *mutex_bar;

int main() {
    static const char *semname1 = "Semaphore1";
    static const char *semname2 = "Semaphore2";

    pthread_t tid;

    mutex_stu = sem_open(semname1, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    if (mutex_stu == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "ERROR creating semaphore semname1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    mutex_bar = sem_open(semname2, O_CREAT, 0777, 1);
   if (mutex_bar == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "ERROR creating semaphore semname2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, bartender, &tid);
    for(int i=0; i < NSTUDENTS; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, student, &tid);
    }

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    sem_unlink(semname1);
    sem_unlink(semname2);

    printf("Exiting the program...\n");
}


//Called by a student process. Do not modify this.
void drink_and_think() {
    // Sleep time in milliseconds
    int st = rand() % 10;
    sleep(st);
}

// Called by a student process. Do not modify this.
void get_serving(int id) {
    if (servings > 0) {
        servings -= 1;
    } else {
        servings = 0;
    }
    printf("ID %d got a serving. %d left\n", id, servings);
}

// Called by the bartender process.
void refill_barrel()
{
    servings = 1 + rand() % 10;
    printf("Barrel refilled up to -> %d\n", servings);
}

//-- Implement a synchronized version of the student
void* student(void* ptr) {
    int id = *(int*)ptr;
    printf("Started student %d\n", id);
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(mutex_stu);
        if(servings > 0) {
            get_serving(id);
        } else {
            sem_post(mutex_bar);
            continue;
        }
        sem_post(mutex_stu);
        drink_and_think();
    }
    return NULL;
}

//-- Implement a synchronized version of the bartender
void* bartender(void* ptr) {
    int id = *(int*)ptr;
    printf("Started bartender %d\n", id);
    //sleep(5);
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(mutex_bar);
        if(servings <= 0) {
            refill_barrel();
        } else {
            printf("Bar skipped sem_wait()!\n");
        }
        sem_post(mutex_stu);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You are not using synchronization primitives correctly. If you need a mutex, use a pthread_mutex_t. If you need a semaphore, don't call it a "mutex", it's not one.

Comment: This always prints the `Bar skipped sem_wait()` message once on startup (as you start with servings=10 and mutex_bar=1), but otherwise runs just fine on both Linux and OSX for me.  Also runs fine on FreeBSD after changing the semaphore names to be valid (FreeBSD is more picky about that).

Comment: Thanks for your comment n.m. I have some study to do obviously... Theres no better time than now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you run the program, you're creating named semaphores with initial values, but since your threads never exit (they're infinite loops), you never get to the `sem_unlink` calls to delete those semaphores.  If you kill the program (with ctrl-C or any other way), the semaphores will still exist in whatever state they are in.  So if you run the program again, the `sem_open` calls will succeed (because you don't use `O_EXCL`), but they won't reset the semaphore value or state, so they might be in some odd state.

So you should make sure to call `sem_unlink` when the program STARTS, before calling `sem_open`.  Better yet, don't use named semaphores at all -- use `sem_init` to initialize a couple of unnamed semaphores instead.

Comment: You, kind sir, are my favourite person at present, thank you. Can you confirm for me this: if I was to use sem_init() and proceed to exit the program without calling sem_destroy() on said unnamed semaphores  could I still expect to experience undefined behaviour?

Comment: No, there's no need to actually call `sem_destroy` before exiting the program as exiting will automatically destroy the semaphore.  That's the point of using unnamed semaphores -- they have no name other than their address, and if that address is private to a process (not in shared memory), then only that process can access that semaphore.  When you restart the program, you get fresh new memory and fresh new semaphores, and any data from previous runs is gone.

Comment: Thank you for getting back you have been a great help. Would you be able to help me understand a further difference between OSX and Linux behaviour when it comes to Pthreads? If I replace the above named semaphores with unnamed semaphores using sem_init() Linux, once again, behaves as expected and OSX lets my 'bartender' thread run wild through the sem_wait() call as if t doesn't exist. Is this another logical error due to my limited knowledge of the way the OS is handling these semaphores?

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe on OSX -- it runs fine when I run it (and runs fine with the named semaphores if I delete them first so they get recreated correctly), so I suspect there may be something odd/broken about your OSX setup.

Comment: Thats very interesting as Im sure I have experienced the exact behaviour on both my MacBook Pro and my Mac Pro both on ML. The mystery continues. Thanks very much for all your help anyhow, cheers.